# Prove that $X \in L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega ,\mathscr{F}, P)$ be probability space.
Let $X_n$ be independent identically distribution random variables, and $S_n:=X_1+\cdots +X_n$.
If $p>0$, $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^{1/p}}=0$ a.s., then $E|X_1|^p<\infty$

I know  by Fubini's theorem, $E|X_1|^p=\int P(|X_1|^p>x)dx =\int P(|X_1|>x^{1/p})dx$

But, I can't prove it is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $E|X_1|^p=\infty$,

As you noted
\begin{align*}
E|X_1|^p&=\int_0^{\infty} P(|X_1|^p>x)dx \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(|X_1|^p>n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(|X_n|^p>n)
\end{align*}
Hence, by Borel-Cantelli
$\{|X_n|> n^{1/p} \,\,\text{i.o.}\}$ holds almost surely.

So,
$$\frac{S_{n}}{n^{1/p}} = \frac{S_{n-1}}{n^{1/p}} +\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}}\Longrightarrow \frac{S_{n}}{n^{1/p}} -\frac{S_{n-1}}{(n-1)^{1/p}} \frac{(n-1)^{1/p}}{n^{1/p}}=\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}},$$
 but the LHS goes to zero almost surely, whereas the RHS is not. Which gives the desired contradiction.